# Using this to define function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am learning angular and trying to use a controller, but the ng-click does not work (the function is not called). The chrome extension Batarang tells that the function is defined as null, why?

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})


.controller("TodoControl", function Controller() {
    var thisRef = this;

    this.todos = [
        {
            text: "mein todo 1",
            done: false
        },
        {
            text: "mein todo 2",
            done: true
        }
    ];

    this.newEntry = "hallo";

    this.AddEntry = function () {
        console.log("adding");
        thisRef.todos.push({
            text: this.newEntry,
            done: false
        });
        thisRef.newEntry = "";
    }

});
```

```html
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <div ng-controller="TodoControl as ctr" class="container">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="t in ctr.todos">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input class="form-control todoFormControl" type="checkbox" ng-model="t.done"><span>{{t.text}}</span></label>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                
                
                <label><input class="todoNewTaskIn" type="text" placeholder="New Task" value="{{ctr.newEntry}}" Style="border: 1px solid gray;" ><button class="button" ng-click="ctr.AddEntry()">Add</button></label>
                
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
```

This is an ionic app (so ionic including angular is included)

Edit: here a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/duowfLsn/

Comment: Put it up in a place where it'll run, jsfiddle for example

Comment: what is in html file?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/duowfLsn/ @patrick-reck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your button out of the  section and it should work. Updated your example

```
<label>
<input class="todoNewTaskIn" type="text" placeholder="New Task" value="{{ctr.newEntry}}" Style="border: 1px solid gray;" >
<button class="button" ng-click="ctr.AddEntry()">Add</button>
</label>
```

becomes

```
<label>
<input class="todoNewTaskIn" type="text" placeholder="New Task" value="{{ctr.newEntry}}" Style="border: 1px solid gray;" />
</label>
<button class="button" ng-click="ctr.addEntry()">Add</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/duowfLsn/3/

Comment: I am not sure and don't want to say this _is_ the answer, but labels have a click behavior - if you use the `for` attr of a label, when you click the label the id'd element is highlighted (such as a textbox). Because of this, perhaps the label click intercepts and the button click never fires?